# combine 2 queries

Tags: sql, join

I have two queries which i would like to combine
There are 4 tables which are linked. 
user, group, policy, source

1st query i get the users with the respective policy id.

1st Query:

```
Select users.ID as UserID,users.Username,   
policy.ID as PolicyID,policy.PolicyName 
from users join groups on group.ID = user.groupID_FK 
join policy on users.policyID_FK = policy.ID
```

2nd Query: Here i need to match the policyID_FK  and apply the path. the source type should be 0, it is possible that there is no entry of datasource type o for that  policyID_FK .

```
Select Path, policyID_FK from source
WHERE SourceType = 0 and policyID_FK  = 1
```

Here instead of giving policyID_FK  = 1 i want to join this query with the above query.

Please help. I know i am not much clear but please ask if you don't understand something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select users.ID as UserID,users.Username, policy.ID as PolicyID,policy.PolicyName, source.Path
from users join groups on group.ID = user.groupID_FK 
   join policy on group.policyID_FK = policy.ID
   left join source
      on group.policyID_FK = source.policyID_FK
      and SourceType = 0
```

Use left join when you know that right table might not have matching records. Append any filter you have beside join to left-join filter, because if you put it in where it will remove rows you want to retrieve.

Comment: the users dont have a policyID_fk. it is in the group table. This is the reason i have to join the users and group first.

Comment: i just changed group.policyID_FK = source.policyID_FK to policy.ID = source.policyID_FK in the end.

Comment: It's fine, I just like to skip to the end as early as I can - so that joins appear as a line, a=>b=>c. It is a matter of taste, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
Select  users.ID as UserID,
        users.Username,   
        policy.ID as PolicyID,
        policy.PolicyName,
        source.Path
FROM    users INNER JOIN groups 
            ON group.ID = user.groupID_FK 
        INNER JOIN policy 
            ON users.policyID_FK = policy.ID
        INNER JOIN source 
            ON users.policyID_FK = source.policyID_FK
-- You can add conditions here
```